# Interchangeability of $\limsup$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, quantifiers

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of real random variables on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and let $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Note that

\begin{align} \limsup_n\,[X_n\geq a] &= \bigcap_{n}\bigcup_{k\geq n}[X_k\geq a]\\
 &= \{\omega\in\Omega\colon \forall_n\exists_{k\geq n}X_k(\omega)\geq a\}\\
 &= \{\omega\in\Omega\colon \forall_n\sup_{k\geq n}X_k(\omega)\geq a\}\\
 &= \{\omega\in\Omega\colon \inf_n\sup_{k\geq n}X_k(\omega)\geq a\}\\
 &= [\limsup_n X_n\geq a]\\
\end{align}

(Is this even correct?)

When can we change the $\limsup$ "into the set"? It seems to work for functions on the left side of $\geq$ as then $\inf_n$ translates to "and" and $\sup$ translates to "or".

I really like the analogies $\bigcap\leftrightarrow\forall$ and $\bigcup\leftrightarrow\exists$. Is there a more general framework for extending these to $$\bigcap\leftrightarrow\inf\leftrightarrow\forall\quad\text{and}\quad \bigcup\leftrightarrow\sup\leftrightarrow\exists?$$

Comment: Typo - first equation, right side - should be $X_k\ge a$.  Major question - the first line has a lim sup of a random variable compared to a number.  Do you mean it for  all realizations of$X_n(\omega)$?

Comment: @herbsteinberg Thank you, edited. Answering your question: To me, $[X_n\geq a]$ is the set of all $\omega\in\Omega$ s.t. $X_n(\omega)\geq a$. So, in the first line, I am speaking of a $\limsup$ of sets.

Comment: It looks to me to be obvious in a way.  You want the equation to hold for all$\omega$.  However as you have, it will hold for each $\omega$ individually, so it follows that it holds for all.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @herbsteinberg Yes, I think the equation is true, too. I rather stated it as an example leading to the second part of the question, that is I am mainly interested in how one could generalise the situation. I could imagine it leading to lattices or something similar?

Comment: I don't really understand the second part.   "into the set"?